# Backbone Model attributes are not binding value to view when silent is true

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I am facing an issue while setting a value to a model.

Here's my code:

```
SuperModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    initialize: function() {
        //some code......
    }
});

ChildModel = SuperModel.extend({

    initialize: function() {

        //some code..........
        SuperModel.prototype.initialize.call(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

At some part of my view, I am trying to set a value to a model (instance of childModel) with `{ silent : true }`.

The model is bound with the view using `ModelBinder`.

```
this.model.set('firstName','tom',{silent:true}); // Not Working
this.model.set('firstName','tom'); //  Working
this.model.set('firstName','tom',{silent:true}).trigger('change'); // Not Working
```

When I remove `SuperModel.prototype.initialize.call(this,arguments);`,  `silent:true` is working (value started setting to UI).

Here I can see the value in my model but is not reflecting on my UI.

Comment: Can you provide more info as this is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue was in the parent model `SuperModel` I had a line of code which is

```
this.set('editedElements', someValue);
```

I do not know the real reason why the value didn't reflect on the ui when I passes `{ silent: true }` as option but later when I removed the code `this.set(...)` it started working.

I have modified it like the following

```
this.set('editedAttributes'),...) -> this.attributes['editeAttributes'] = ...
```

Now those model values where I passed `{ silent: true }` is reflecting on UI.

Comment: when a parent model calls `set` or whatever function, you need to pass the options you received. I'll try to update my answer to demonstrate that.

Comment: In my case i decided not to go with set but access it straight from attributes object.

Answer (score 2):

First, if you're going to pass `arguments` to its parent `initialize` function, you need to use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and not [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

```
SuperModel.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
```

Then, if you pass `{ silent: true }`, [the Backbone's events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog) are not triggered. If you want to simulate the events later, you should simulate them correctly:

```
var options = { silent: true },
    value = 'tom';

this.model.set('firstName', value, options);
this.model.trigger('change:firstName', this.model, value, options)
          .trigger('change', this.model, options);
```

But that defeats the purpose of the `silent` option.